# Python 'in' operator doesn't work in array

Tags: python

i'm quite a beginner in python and making 2D random walker program.(up & down and left & right). I hope the walker not to go the position where it visited.

So, I made some arrays and one is the array which collect history of coordinate.
And I also defined a function which returns possible option at specific position. It seems that the functions doesn't do

```
def opt(histo,cur):
  tmp=[]
  tmp.append([cur[0]+1,cur[1]])
  tmp.append([cur[0]-1,cur[1]])
  tmp.append([cur[0],cur[1]+1])
  tmp.append([cur[0],cur[1]-1])
  tmp.remove(histo[-2])
  print "current history : ",histo
  print "current tmp : ",tmp
  print "current pos : ",cur
  for i in tmp:
    if i in histo:
      print str(i)+" was detected!!"
      tmp.remove(i)
  return tmp
```

The code results in

...

current history :  [[0, 0], [0, -1], [0, -2], [-1, -2], [-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-2, 0], [-3, 0], [-3, -1], [-3, -2], [-3, -3], [-4, -3], [-5, -3], [-6, -3], [-7, -3], [-7, -2], [-6, -2], [-5, -2], [-5, -1], [-4, -1], [-4, -      2]]

current tmp :  [[-3, -2], [-5, -2], [-4, -3]]

current pos :  [-4, -2]

[-3, -2] was detected!!

[-4, -3] was detected!!

After elimination :  [[-5, -2]]

....

Why [-5,-2] is safe in this case?

Comment: Lists are the wrong data structure. Use a set containing tuples.

Comment: please make your question readable, apart from problems with formatting, language is hard to understand

Comment: Also, mutating a list you're iterating over -- as with `.remove()` -- messes up your iterators, which is why the loop isn't covering everything.

Comment: Sorry m.wasowski and Thanks Duffy. Sorry for my english skill..

Comment: ...and if you want both fast membership checks _and_ order retention, use two data structures -- one set, one list -- both containing tuples, not lists. Right now, your code will slow down as the list grows, because checking whether something is `in` a list is an `O(n)` operation; a set won't have that problem.

Comment: Thank you duffy... You really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest possible change follows:

```
def opt(histo,cur):
  tmp=[]
  tmp.append([cur[0]+1,cur[1]])
  tmp.append([cur[0]-1,cur[1]])
  tmp.append([cur[0],cur[1]+1])
  tmp.append([cur[0],cur[1]-1])
  tmp.remove(histo[-2])
  print "current history : ",histo
  print "current tmp : ",tmp
  print "current pos : ",cur
  for i in list(tmp):
    if i in histo:
      print str(i)+" was detected!!"
      tmp.remove(i)
  return tmp
```

That is to say, it changes `tmp` to `list(tmp)`. That way, you're not iterating over the same copy of the list that you're modifying.

That said, `in` is inefficient when used on lists, and tuples should be used for the inner data structure for performance and correctness reasons. So you should also change `[cur[0]+1, cur[1]]` to `(cur[0]+1, cur[1])` for all references, and modify the type of `histo` to be a set.